# GitHub pull requests was not commented with sonarQube analysis

Tags: jenkins, github, sonarqube, continuous-integration

Our gitHub pull request is not updated with SonarQube analysis report comment.We are recently upgraded from Sonarqube Version 5.6.3 to SonarQube version  6.7.7. We used GitHub Plugin in version 5.6.3. In jenkins code we mentioned,

```
 sonar.analysis.mode=preview
```

How to push the SonarQube analysis report as a comment to gitPull request.What is the alternate for GitHub Plugin in SonarQube version 6.7.7.Could you please guide us on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change mode to publish.
Then it will works

Comment: [ERROR] The GitHub plugin is only intended to be used in preview or issues mode. Please set 'sonar.analysis.mode'. I have got this error.

Comment: GIT PLUGIN is working fine with SonarQube version 5.6.3, I need alternate for this plugin in SonarQube version 6.7.7. As per the GIT PLUGIN docs, it is deprecated from SonarQube version 6.6

Comment: You need a different (paid) SonarQube edition. See [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/what-is-the-best-practice-for-continuing-the-deprecated-preview-mode/1562/2);